# CDI alternatives with priority not working as expected? What would be the possible cause?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

When I tried to experiment `CDI` `alternatives` with `priority`, it's working the reverse way, The bean with the least priority was chosen instead of the highest priority bean. How alternatives with priority works?

`beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <alternatives>
        <class>org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity.RegularGreeting</class>
        <class>org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity.FancyGreeting</class>
        <class>org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity.PriorityGreeting</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

`Greeting.java`

```
package org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity;

    public interface Greeting {

        public String greet(final String greet);

    }
```

`FancyGreeting.java`

```
package org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;

@Alternative
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION + 1)
public class FancyGreeting implements Greeting {

    @Override
    public String greet(String greet) {
        return "schöner Tag,  " + greet;
    }        
}
```

`PriorityGreeting.java`

```
package org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;

@Alternative
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION + 2)
public class PriorityGreeting implements Greeting {

    @Override
    public String greet(String greet) {
        return "der Vorrang, Hello, " + greet;
    }
}
```

`RegularGreeting.java`

```
package org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;

@Alternative
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class RegularGreeting implements Greeting {

    @Override
    public String greet(String greet) {
        return "hello " + greet;
    }
}
```

`AlternativesPriorityController.java`

```
 package org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.controller;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

    import org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.entity.Greeting;

    @ApplicationScoped
    public class AlternativesPriorityController {

        @Inject
        Greeting greet;

        public String getGreet(String string) {
            return greet.greet(string);
        } 
    }
```

`AlternativesPriorityResource.java`

```
package org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.boundary;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import org.bala.java.jee.cdi.alternatives.priority.controller.AlternativesPriorityController;

    @Path("/alternatives")
    public class AlternativesPriorityResource {

        @Inject
        AlternativesPriorityController controller;

        @Path("/priority")
        @GET
        public Response getGreet() {
            return Response.ok(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("Greet", controller.getGreet("Princess !")).build(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        }
    }
```

outputs :

```
{
  "Greet": "hello Princess !"
}
```

But the desired output is,

```
    {
      "Greet": "der Vorrang, Hello, Princess !"
    }
```

Thanks.

Updated `beans.xml` as suggested by @BalusC

`beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all"> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you registered them as well in `beans.xml` with `RegularGreeting` ranked highest. XML configuration always overrides annotation configuration. In other words, the `@Alternative` is completely ignored.

Just remove the whole `<alternatives>` section from `beans.xml`, then `@Alternative` can do its job together with `@Priority`.

Comment: I tried removing the entire `alternatives` section from `beans.xml`, still, the bean with least priority (RegularGreeting) was chosen instead of high priority bean (PriorityGreeting)

Comment: I am using Payara Full versioned 4.1.2

Comment: After a clean build and redeploy, works as expected, Though enabled auto publishing in payara I have to deploy it the legacy way in eclipse. Thanks @BalusC

Comment: @BalusC A bit of a correction, XML configuration does NOT always override priority annotation. This is in fact undefined by spec and left up to implementation. What you observe is Weld specific behaviour.

Comment: @Siliarus: any other annotable Java EE container managed artifact is overrideable via some XML file, think of CDI managed beans (beans.xml), JSF artifacts (faces-config.xml), JPA entities (orm.xml), EJB interceptors (ejb.xml), WebServlets/Filters/Listeners (web.xml), etc. For most of them it's even explicitly specified. This allows overriding annotated behavior externally without the need to rebuild the application. It would surprise me if an implementor decides to do the inverse as that would make the application unconfigureable externally.

Comment: Some time ago (may be well over a year now) I checked OWB implementation of CDI and they simply blew up if you enabled alternative both ways. Guess it's different now, just saying.

Comment: @Siliarus: OWB is buggy anyway.